# Independent t-test with an aov-object in R

Tags: r, t-test

Is there a simple way to compute independent t-tests with an aov object, similar to how pairwise comparisons can be computed by `pairs(emmeans(aov.object,~variable)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to discern what the question really is. This answer is based on this guess:

> Is it possible to use `emmeans()` to do all independent *t* tests comparing several samples, two at a time?

#### Pooled t tests: NO (similar but not exactly)

The answer to that question is "not exactly". I'll illustrate with the `InsectSprays` data in the **datasets** package. We may fit this `aov` model:

```
> fm1 <- aov(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays)
```

Then use `emmeans` to compare the sprays:

```
> library("emmeans")
> pairs(emmeans(fm1, "spray"), adjust = "none")

 contrast estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
 A - B      -0.833 1.6 66 -0.520  0.6045 
 A - C      12.417 1.6 66  7.755  <.0001 
 A - D       9.583 1.6 66  5.985  <.0001 
 A - E      11.000 1.6 66  6.870  <.0001 
 A - F      -2.167 1.6 66 -1.353  0.1806 
 B - C      13.250 1.6 66  8.276  <.0001 
 B - D      10.417 1.6 66  6.506  <.0001 
 B - E      11.833 1.6 66  7.391  <.0001 
 B - F      -1.333 1.6 66 -0.833  0.4080 
 C - D      -2.833 1.6 66 -1.770  0.0814 
 C - E      -1.417 1.6 66 -0.885  0.3795 
 C - F     -14.583 1.6 66 -9.108  <.0001 
 D - E       1.417 1.6 66  0.885  0.3795 
 D - F     -11.750 1.6 66 -7.339  <.0001 
 E - F     -13.167 1.6 66 -8.223  <.0001
```

This does perform *t* tests comparing two means at a time (adding `adjust = "none"` specifies that there is no multiplicity adjustment, so each test is taken as-is with no reference to the other test). The values of the means being compared are exactly the means that would be compared if you had run `t.test()` separately with each pair of samples. *However*, these results are not exactly the same as the `t.test()` results would be, because the error variance in `fm1` is estimated by pooling all 6 samples together, whereas `t.test()` would use the variability in only the two samples used in a particular test. I'll show this explicitly for the `A - B` comparison:

```
> t.test(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, subset = (spray %in% c("A","B")), var.equal = TRUE)

    Two Sample t-test

data:  count by spray
t = -0.45352, df = 22, p-value = 0.6546
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.643994  2.977327
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       14.50000        15.33333
```

Note that the *t* ratio is slightly different, and there are 22 d.f. rather than 66, because only the variances of the two samples were pooled.

#### Welch t tests: YES

It *is* possible to use a similar method to obtain all of the *t* tests exactly, under different assumptions that the variances are not all equal. This requires a model that does not specify equal variances, as `aov()` does. Here is the same example using a `gls()` model:

```
> library("nlme")
> fm2 <- gls(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | spray))

> pairs(emmeans(fm2, "spray", df.method = "boot"), adjust = "none")
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 A - B      -0.833 1.837 21.8 -0.454  0.6547 
 A - C      12.417 1.477 14.7  8.407  <.0001 
 A - D       9.583 1.542 16.7  6.214  <.0001 
 A - E      11.000 1.451 13.9  7.580  <.0001 
 A - F      -2.167 2.252 20.5 -0.962  0.3473 
 B - C      13.250 1.358 15.5  9.754  <.0001 
 B - D      10.417 1.429 17.8  7.289  <.0001 
 B - E      11.833 1.330 14.5  8.894  <.0001 
 B - F      -1.333 2.177 19.5 -0.613  0.5472 
 C - D      -2.833 0.920 20.9 -3.078  0.0057 
 C - E      -1.417 0.758 21.6 -1.868  0.0754 
 C - F     -14.583 1.882 13.2 -7.748  <.0001 
 D - E       1.417 0.879 19.6  1.612  0.1229 
 D - F     -11.750 1.934 14.5 -6.076  <.0001 
 E - F     -13.167 1.862 12.7 -7.071  <.0001 

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite
```

Note that the test of the `A - B` comparison is identical to that of `t.test()`, which by default takes the variances to be unequal:

```
> t.test(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, subset = (spray %in% c("A","B")))

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  count by spray
t = -0.45352, df = 21.784, p-value = 0.6547
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.646182  2.979515
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       14.50000        15.33333
```

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you!